# How to get count of all rows of table when using GroupBy() instead of grouped records count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

When I use Group by along with Count() on my select statement it is grouping records and returning each group count.

I want to get grand total of all  records of table with Group By  . How do I get that.

I need result similar to below

```
GroupCount  Dept  GrandTotalOfAllRows
 2          CEC      6
 1          ECE      6
 3          CSE      6
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use window functions: the logic is to do a window `sum()` of the aggregate counts over the whole dataset.

That would look like :

```
select 
    count(*) GroupCount,
    dept, 
    sum(count(*)) over () GrandTotalOfAllRows
from mytable
group by dept
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **Partition By** in your query

```
....      
,SUM(Count(*)) OVER () AS GrandTotalOfAllRows
from Table 
GROUP by dept
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.

```
SELECT
  dept
  ,COUNT(*) AS GroupCount
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) AS TotalCount
FROM table
GROUP BY
  dept
```